How to avoid SBA server calling monitored pods that are just restarted by k8s and presumably not yet healthy
Spring Boot Admin Server information

Version: 3.3.3

Spring Boot version: 3.3.2

Configured Security: OAuth

Webflux or Servlet application: servlet


Client information

Spring Boot versions: 3.3.2

Used discovery mechanism: kubernetes

Webflux or Servlet application: servlet


We are using SBA in kubernetes cluster with istio and strict mTLS and headless service + Host header for SBA networking.
We see that after a pod restart (of the monitored SB apps) a couple of GET and OPTIONS requests to the SB app's actuators are returning 503. Those errors pop up only for a short period of time, after a minute or so the actuators return 200 responses.
Do you have an explanation for this? SBA server would start polling from the SB apps once k8s API marks them as live and healthy, right? Or does SBA server ignore the health of the container during service discovery? I would assume that SBA server respects the health state of a container provided by k8s api and then starts polling according to spring.boot.admin.monitor.status-interval
Another explanation could be that after pod restart the IP address changes and SBA server is still polling the old and outdated pod IP.
Any idea what could cause this problem?
